# How to write lines (for loop) with specific format with different variables in python (mix between string and integers ) in Python

Tags: python

I would like to write the following lines as it is but with different variables (a,z and g) as the following:
For i In {1:a+1}
b~{i} = z+(i-1)*g;
EndFor

I mean I have a code defines the a,z,g (but they might be different each time): I do not want python to calculate the loop, I just wanna the above lines to be written with same (loop format) in a text file
here as the code I think .. any suggestion or documentation to help me ...
Not sure how could I write what i want with different variables

```
import numpy as np
a=3
z=5
g=2
fileID                                =    open(output.dat,"w")
fileID.write('%s%s%d%s%d%s%d%s%d%s \n'% 
 ('Point(1)=','{',0,',',0,',',a,',',z,'}'))
 fileID.write('\n')
 # I NEED TO WRITE HERE the following for loop but with different a, z and g ?
For i In {1:a+1}
b~{i} = z+(i-1)*g;
EndFor
```

Thanks,

Comment: if you are trying to create a string and add it to the file, then try value = 'For i In {1:'+str(a)+'+1}'+str(b)+'~{i} = z+(i-1)*'+str(g)+';EndFor'

Comment: I'm intrigued by the *b~{i}* syntax. What does that do?

Comment: @OldBill
Thanks for your comment, 
b~{i} syntax same as b{i}
but if possible .. I wanna write them as it is just need to change b

Comment: @roshanok
Thank you but I do not think making str(a) and b can help as I need them as integer
Or you think this won't effect ??
Also need them be in separate lines .. as mentioned in the question 
Let me know ... even in python example if possible

Comment: @Sci_tech *b{i}* doesn't look like valid Python syntax either

Comment: @Sci_tech Since you are storing it in the text file, the str() wont effect the data type.
Try this for multiline value = "For i In {1:'+str(a)+'+1}\nstr(b)+'~{i} = z+(i-1)*'+str(g)+';\nEndFor"

Comment: @OldBill I see, but I just wanna write them in file cause I will need them for another software and thats why I want the same format 
variables numbers only change 
Did you get what I meant ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import numpy as np
a=3
z=5
g=2
fileID = open('output.dat',"w")
s = "For i In {1:"+str(a)+"+1}\n\t"+str(z)+"~{i} = z+(i-1)*"+str(g)+";\nEndFor"
fileID.write(s)
fileID.close()
```